# HIGHCHARTS / GANTT Multiple tasks same lane using hierarchical structure

Tags: highcharts

We would like to ask a question, we have several lanes (Y categories), mainly we create many lanes per category, in my example below, the cat LXXXXXX has 2 lanes, one with milestones the other lane with a pill, our question is, can web setup the following type of structure in a hierarchical way? in other words  Thank you for all your help.

[image]

Comment: Hierarchical you mean [yAxis.type](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.type) treegrid? Check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1va237r5/) but you need to know that you can choose only one type of xaxis.

Comment: Hi @SebastianHajdus, thank you for your prompt answer, yes, something similar to what you show but with multiple tasks and or milestones in one lane... in other words, we are already doing that, but lanes are not grouped, is there a way to group y lanes?

Comment: When you set [yAxis.uniqueNames](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.uniqueNames), [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v9q73tna/) you get options to program milestones alongside, unfortunately, this options it's not implemented to axis type category, you can report it as a future request.